# Save embedded pdf from website

Tags: javascript, c#, html, c#-4.0, webclient

I am writing a small C# application to manage our Safety data Sheets (of chemicals) from our suppliers.

At the moment I manually search for the chemical and save the pdf and add a link to the pdf in my program. The problem is I still have many chemical to go so it would be better to automate the process.

For example: A chemical has the following part number: 271004

The link containing the pdf is here:

[Link](http://www.sigmaaldrich.com/MSDS/MSDS/PleaseWaitMSDSPage.do?language=EN-generic&country=NL&brand=SIAL&productNumber=271004&PageToGoToURL=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.sigmaaldrich.com%2Fcatalog%2Fsearch%3Finterface%3DAll%26term%3D271004%26N%3D0%26mode%3Dmatch%2520partialmax%26focus%3Dproduct%26lang%3Den%26region%3DNL)

I have been reading the page source but cannot find a link to the pdf

But my knowledge of html/javascript is to limited at the moment.....

Is there any way to extract the pdf from the website?

Thanks in advance for any advice :)

Comment: Short answer: Yes there is a way. Addendum: [What have you tried](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com)?

Answer (score 13):

For those trying to download a PDF file on Firefox and Chrome, put the mouse pointer anywhere within the PDF area and press <kbd>control</kbd> + <kbd>s</kbd> (on windows / linux) or  <kbd>⌘</kbd>  + <kbd>s</kbd> (on mac). Doing so will download the file.

Answer (score 2):

Look in the page for an iframe element with id "`msdsPageFrame`". The `src` attribute of that element contains the url to your PDF. Download that url.

If you have questions about how to download an URL or how to parse a page in search for an id, ask another question.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the reply. The only problem is that the number in the link is not related to the part number, so it becomes difficult to automate..I would like to be able to get the pdf based on the product number.

Comment: @JR_ You can automate, the number is in the original URL, so download the orginal URL, parse it. Find id "msdsPageFrame". Read src attribute, download that link and done!

Comment: What do you mean with "The number is the original URL"? The url to the pdf is http://www.sigmaaldrich.com/MSDS/MSDS/PrintMSDSAction.do?name=msdspdf_1410280031038377. How is this number (1410280031038377) related to the part number or "original url"

Comment: Is IN the url. www.sigmaaldrich.com/MSDS/MSDS/DisplayMSDSPage.do?country=NL&language=EN-generic&productNumber=271004&brand=SIAL&PageToGoToURL=null check the **productNumber** part

Comment: Thanks :) However, downloading is not possible because the pdf is first generated... (takes a few seconds). However the download complete event is triggered right away.

Answer (score 0):

Now I am able to access the pdf file direct using an product code:

www.sigmaaldrich.com/MSDS/MSDS/DisplayMSDSPage.do?country=NL&language=EN-generic‌​&productNumber=271004&brand=SIAL&PageToGoToURL=null

Using the following code I try to download the pdf:

```
        private void Download()
    {
        webClient.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(Completed);                   // Uses the Event Handler to check whether the download is complete
        webClient.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(ProgressChanged);  // Uses the Event Handler to check for progress made
        webClient.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri("http://www.sigmaaldrich.com/MSDS/MSDS/DisplayMSDSPage.do?country=NL&language=EN-generic&productNumber=271004&brand=SIAL&PageToGoToURL=null"), @"C:\Users\test\Downloads\newfile.pdf");           // Defines the URL and destination directory for the downloaded file
    }

    private void ProgressChanged(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler");
    }

    private void Completed(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("AsyncCompletedEventHandler");
    }
```

However this does not work. The problem is that the pdf is first generated (takes a few seconds). However, the AsyncCompletedEventHandler is triggered right away. I think this is the problem why the pdf file is not downloaded.