# Extract embedded pdf document from a webpage

Tags: python, pdf, mime-types

I am trying to write a Python program that is able to extract a PDF file that is embedded in a website, e.g., in a PDF viewer. However, I haven't yet been able to find a robust way to accomplish this.

Is there a way or best practice to identify PDFs based on MIME-type maybe?

Comment: [mime-type](https://stackoverflow.com/a/312258/6689249) is `application/pdf`

Comment: Hello Aiven. Thanks for your reply. But in this case, how can you identify the mime-type if the content is embedded?

Comment: there is also [some](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26230781/6689249) suggestion on how to download pdf. And can you provide example with embedded pdf (site link maybe)?

Comment: Of course, I just went online to find a random webpage that includes an embedded pdf: https://issuu.com/futurepublishing/docs/art274.issuu Of course they have a download link here, but that's not the aim. It's really about how to identify that there's a pdf embedded. :)

Answer (score -1):

So basically what you need is to search for `iframe` in html page and check `src` attribute, it should contain url to the pdf file.

For example:
`<iframe src="/pdfjs/web/viewer.html?file=%2Fpdf%2Fsample-3pp.pdf" style="border: none; width: 100%; height: 100%;" frameborder="0"></iframe>` from https://pdfobject.com/examples/pdfjs-forced.html

And so needed pdf url will be: `https://pdfobject.com/pdfjs/web/viewer.html?file=%2Fpdf%2Fsample-3pp.pdf`

Notice that not every pdf web-readers provide ability to check location of file. For example [site](https://issuu.com/futurepublishing/docs/art274.issuu) that you've shared don't do that.

You can load html page with `urllib` or `requests` and search for html-tag with `beautifulsoup`, or use `scrapy`, or tons of other tool.